# Ubuntu is renaming my mount point for a hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, drive

I have a hard drive connected to my computer, it's located at `/media/hassan/Hassan HD`. This does not normally change when I reboot, but it did this time. Now it's at `/media/hassan/Hassan HD1`. Not sure why. I tried deleting `/media/hassan/Hassan HD` and then restarting, but this did not change anything.

This move breaks some things, like the Plex server I have running. How do I ensure that the drive mounts in the same spot every time?

Comment: Does your drive have two labels?

Comment: How can I tell?

Comment: What filesystem is your hdd?

Comment: The external drive is NTFS

Comment: Please post the output of sudo ntfs-label /dev/sdxx (where /dev/sdxx is your hard drive?

Comment: `Hassan HD` is the output

Comment: Which one would you like? Hasan Hd or Hassan Hd1?

Comment: HD without the 1 preferably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Type `ntfs-label /dev/sdxx` and store this for future reference.
2. Type `ntfs-label /dev/sdxx <new label>`.
3. Type `ntfs-label /dev/sdxx <new label>` again.

This *should* work because it overwrites both labels. If this dosen't work you may need to reformat the disk.

If it has nothing on it, just run the following command:

```
mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdxx
```

If it does have something on it, run:

```
cp /mountpoint/ /location/with/enough/space/to/copy/all/the/files/on/another/disk
mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdxx
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I did `sudo ntfslabel /dev/sdb2 Hassan\ HD`, once I unmounted first. When I remounted with `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb2`, it worked. The problem is it reverted as soon as I restarted. I think it might be my Plex server that's trying to write to the mounted drive before it's actually mounted. Not sure what to do about that, but at least now I know what's causing it.

Comment: Is this a major server, or is it just a home server? Cause if it is just a home server, stop plex on boot and follow the commands.

Comment: It's a home server. What do you mean by stop Plex and follow commands? Each time I start the computer?

Comment: Oh wait it was actually another service causing it. I think I can just stop the other service, and I'm good to go. Thanks!